# Issues installing/compiling mfcuk/libnfc on Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, compile, error-logging, nfc

I am trying to compile this mfcuk version
https://github.com/DrSchottky/mfcuk

I get this error on kali when I try to compile mfcuk
[image]

```
root@kali:~/mfcuk# ./configure
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
./configure: line 3927: syntax error near unexpected token `libnfc,'
./configure: line 3927: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(libnfc, libnfc >= $LIBNFC_REQUIRED_VERSION, , AC_MSG_ERROR([libnfc >= $LIBNFC_REQUIRED_VERSION is mandatory.]))'
root@kali:~/mfcuk#
```

Comment: Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: You should add debugging information: `set -x` in `.\configure` and add `-d` to any `make` calls.

Comment: I did but nothing has changed  @AFH

Comment: You should have seen the expanded error line after variable substitution, and the syntax error should now be more evident.

Comment: how to add debugging information? please give command by command @AFH

Comment: I have already given you enough information. You should look at the `man` pages to see how the debug commands I suggested should be incorporated. I have no idea what commands you are running, so I can't be expected to give you a line-by-line status, though it shouldn't be necessary: unless `./configure` contains a `set +x`, a single `set -x` at the head of the file should suffice, and there won't be so many `make` calls that you can't add `-d` to each of them, possibly with a single, global substitution.